# Invalid option when running bash script on Debian 7

Tags: bash, debian, startup, init

When I run

```
root@Nano:/etc/init.d# ./utserver
```

which is this script http://pastebin.com/c7gxFdci it gives me this output

```
": invalid option"
```

no matter how the arguments are done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your file has DOS `\r\n` line endings. Here's the relevant section from the [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info):

1. **Check whether your script or data has DOS style end-of-line characters**

   - Use `cat -v yourfile` or `echo "$yourvariable" | cat -v` .

     DOS carriage returns will show up as `^M` after each line.

     If you find them, delete them using `dos2unix` (a.k.a. `fromdos`) or `tr -d '\r'`